# How to replace a character in string

Tags: erlang, character, string-operations

I'm writing a function to replace all underscores in a string with dashes. For example:

```
underscores_to_dashes("erlang_is_great") = "erlang-is-great"
```

At the moment I'm using the following function:

```
underscores_to_dashes(String) ->
    [case Char of 95 -> 45; _ -> Char end || Char <- String].
```

In this implementation it's not obvious which character is being replaced with which and I have to use list comprehension and a case statement.

Is there a simpler way to implement such functionality? Perhaps I'm missing some in-built erlang function?

Comment: Th only improvement I've made to this was to relace `95 -> 45` with `$_ -> $-` for better readibility